# Better leave room - how to understand this sentence in context?

Tags: sentence-meaning, translation

Look this sentence:

> Better leave room for more important things, like which wild animals to avoid and whether naked snowboarding is a bad idea'

I saw this sentence in a Python book. I know every single word means, but I can't undersand this whole sentence.

If my point going right, it means that don't stay in your home, it's not a good idea, you should go out to do something more important. Then it says 'like which wild animals'. Does it suggest we go out to look wild animals?

What does the whole sentence mean?

Complete sentence:

> Here you are trying to learn something, while here your brain is, doing you a favor by making sure the learning doesn’t stick. Your brain’s thinking, **better leave room for more important things, like which wild animals to avoid and whether naked snowboarding is a bad idea**. So how do you trick your brain into thinking that your life depends on knowing how to program in Python?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are mistaking the meaning of **room** in that sentence.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[room](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/room)

> 1 - a part of the inside of a building that is separated from other
>   parts by walls, floor, and ceiling
>
> **2** - the amount of space that someone or something needs

The second meaning is the one used in your context.

The text is not exhorting you to leave the building **-1-** and live new experiences but to reserve some space in your brain **-2-** for Python. Your brain may not like that idea at first, because Python may seem useless and difficult to learn. Your brain may think that learning about wild animals or snowboarding dangers is more cool and useful but you have to proof it wrong because Python is an interesting matter, as you would discover if you keep reading.

You have to trick your brain, you have to fight it metaphorically.

Comment: And a clue to the fact that this is the relevant meaning of _room_ is the lack of an article. Room (1) is countable, and would never appear in normal text without an article or specifier. Room (2) is uncountable, and does not need an article.